# PHP Replace 1st occurrence with x and 2nd occurrence of string with y

Tags: php, regex, string

This is a tricky question here is what I am trying to do:

```
$str="abc def abc";
```

I want to replace `first` occurrence of `abc` with `123` and `second` occurrence of `abc` with `456`
Now with preg_match it is possible that I replace first occurrence of abc with 123 like this

```
preg_replace('/abc/', '123', $str, 1);
```

But how to replace the second occurrence with 456 and most importantly how to do it at once and generate the required string (i.e 123 def 456).

Note: Strings are generated from external source.

Thanks Ahmar

Comment: Besides `preg_replace('/abc/', '123', $str, 1); preg_replace('/abc/', '456', $str, 1);`... `preg_replace_callback()` with a callback that maintains a static count of each replacement and can modify its response based on that count

Answer (score 6):

You were very close:

```
$str = preg_replace('/abc/', '123', $str, 1); // will replace first 'abc'
$str = preg_replace('/abc/', '456', $str);    // will replace all others
```

The reason this will work, is because the 2nd regex's first occurence, is actually the 2nd item.
**Pro**: Very readable, very easy to understand and implement
**Con**: the string will be regexed twice (bad for large strings), options are limited

---

If this is not what you want, you can use `preg_replace_callback()`

```
$firstHasBeenFound = false;
function magicFunction($matches){
    global $firstHasBeenFound;
    print_r($matches);
    if( !$firstHasBeenFound ){
        /* do something for the first time */ ;
        $firstHasBeenFound = true; // save for next round
    }
    else{
         /* do something for the test */ ;
    }
}

$str = preg_replace_callback('/abc/', 'magicFunction', $str);
```

**Pro**: A lot more variants can be made, more control over code, only one parse of the string
**Con**: More difficult to read/implement

In this example I use `$firstHasBeenFound`, but you could use a increment to do something each 2nd, or something when you find match 7, etc

Comment: Err... Why use hack when `preg_replace_callback` exists?

Comment: `$firstHasBeenFound` variable will not be available inside your function, so this wouldn't work. You'll have to either use a Closure (see Mark's answer) or use `global` (which is not a good practice anyway) to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?:

```
$str = preg_replace('/abc(.*?)abc/', '123${1}456', $str, 1);
```

Comment: I like this idea, but when you use larger regexes, this will result in a mess. But for small replacements, this would be great

Comment: @Martijn Yeah, possibly it will. Cause it will require to hold the group in $1 and will be heavy for worst case!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="abc def abc ghi abc";
$replacements = array('123', '456');

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/abc/',
    function ($matches) use ($replacements) {
        static $counter = 0;
        $returnValue = $matches[0];
        if (isset($replacements[$counter]))
            $returnValue = $replacements[$counter];
        $counter++;
        return $returnValue;
    },
    $str
);

var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `preg_replace_callback` with `closure` as callback (works in PHP 5.3+).

```
$str = "abc def abc abc def abc";
$a_replc = array('123', '456');
$n = 0;
$str = preg_replace_callback('/abc/', function () use (&$n, $a_replc) {
    return $a_replc[$n++ % count($a_replc)];
}, $str);
```